# Push notification failing after a while on One Signal

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I have an app for iOS which was built using Xamarin.Forms and One Signal. On iOS I am facing an weird issue. I have set up everything for push notification according to the docs (generating push certificate, adding it on key chain and other stuff).

When I upload my .p12 certificate on the One Signal portal (also tried with .p8) it started sending push notification properly but after a while it says and stops sending notifications.

> Your Apple iOS (Production) platform has a Invalid Push Certificate configuration error that is preventing new messages from being sent.

If upload the .p12 again it starts to send notification again and fails again after a while.
I have also tried by renaming the .p12 file but the result is same.

I am running my app on test flight.